# Remove the class from a menu container

Tags: wordpress

Ive changed the container from my menu from DIV to nav, but I also want to get rid of the class attribute. How an I do it? This doesnt seem to work...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array("container" => "nav", "container_class" => '' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question right, Just removing  the "container_class" option like this should work:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array("container" => "nav" )); ?>
```

edited : I just check the documentation and if there is no `conatainer_class` given it replaces it with some default class. After searching google for a while I couldn't find any thing that could filter out your output so I just defined a custom function. Your write this in your functions.php and then instead of calling `wp_nav_menu()` you call this function `custom_wp_nav_menu()` at same place

```
function custom_wp_nav_menu()
{
    $options= array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', // Setting up the location for the main-menu, Main Navigation.
    'menu_class' => 'dropdown', //Adding the class for dropdowns
    'container_id' => 'navwrap', //Add CSS ID to the containter that wraps the menu.
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'container_class' => " ",
    'echo' => false
    );
    $nav = wp_nav_menu($options);
    $nav = str_replace( 'class=" "', '',  $nav );  
    echo $nav;
} // function
```

Comment: if I dont write the "container_class" I get a default class, namely "menu-main-container"

Comment: ok the easiest fix that I found is:<?php wp_nav_menu( array("container" => "nav", "container_class" => " " )); ?>// there is a space between the two quotes ... this would only print <nav class= " "> .... </nav> in html ...

Comment: i just wrote the function above to filter out class=" " from the final html code

Comment: the solution is a little "dirtier" than i would have liked... but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following correctly, could you not go to the source file that stores the wp_nav_menu() function, which is located in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php and remove the code from there?

Look for this defaults section within the orignal file

```
$defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );
```

if you look you have the  tag with id="%1$s" and class="%2$s", remove the class bit and I think that would solve your issue.

I was looking for the same thing, found this post and Killer_Alien_Monk's solution, but decided there had to be a way to modify the orignal function :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I found is to create the container manually like this:

```
<nav id="headerMenu"><?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
    'container' => ''
)); ?></nav>
```

This way, Wordpress can not add a class to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Ended out Solving the problem by editing a few lines located at the the **wp-includes/nav_menu_template.php** like  - line 191 for the *container*:

#### [original source]

```
$class = $args->container_class ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $args->container_class ) . '"' : ' class="menu-'. $menu->slug .'-container"';
```

#### [my edit]

```
$class = $args->container_class ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $args->container_class ) . '"' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `item_wrap` argument, the default `item_wrap` argument is `<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>`

so may you can use something like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array("container" => "nav", "items_wrap" => '<ul>%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you married to the idea of using php? If not, jQuery's removeClass method seems like a likely candidate if you're trying to remove the class dynamically.

Comment: Im not married to php, but using jQuery to modify the output HTML seems a wasteful idea. There should be a method to control the output of HTML, instead of having to "tune" it with jQuery.